# WenXamarin - Web API

Tags: xamarin, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-2

Estou tentando fazer o código do Post da APi e não estou conseguindo realizar o salvamento das informações, já que vem de um relacionamento entre duas tabelas. É uma sistema de vendas, onde tenho duas tabelas, uma que se chama OrdemPedido, onde fica as informações do cliente, forma de pagamento e uma segunda onde fica armazenado os detalhes desse pedido como os produtos que o cliente quer comprar, porém ao gerar o Post da Api só consigo salvar parte do pedido o que se refere a as informações de cliente e forma de pagamento e não salva os detalhes do meu pedido, ou seja, os produtos não aprecem.

```
// POST: api/OrdemPedidoes
    [ResponseType(typeof(OrdemPedido))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostOrdemPedido(OrderRequest orderRequest)
    {
        var details = new List<OrderDetailldTmp>();
        foreach (var detail in orderRequest.Detalhes)
        {
            var product = db.CadProdutoes.Find(detail.ProdutoId);
            if (product != null)
            {
                details.Add(new OrderDetailldTmp
                {
                    Descricao = product.Descricao,
                    Price = product.Precoprazo,
                    ProdutoId = product.ProdutoId,
                    Quantity = detail.Quantity,
                    Desconto = detail.Desconto,

                });
            }
        }

        var newOrderView = new NewOrderView
        {
            Details = details,
            IdCliente = orderRequest.IdCliente,
            Date = orderRequest.Date,
            CityId = orderRequest.CityId,
            FormaPagamentoId = orderRequest.FormaPagamentoId,
            FornecedorId = orderRequest.FornecedorId,
            DataEntrega = orderRequest.DataEntrega,
            HoraIncial = orderRequest.HoraIncial,
            Remarks = orderRequest.Remarks
        };



        var response = MovementsHelper.NewOrder(newOrderView);

        if (response.Succeeded)
        {
            return Ok("Venda Salva!!");
        }

        return BadRequest(response.Message);
    }
```

Comment: Olá @Grasielle, infelizmente com o código que você compartilhou não da para te ajudar muito, mas de acordo com seus dizeres, acredito que o problema está ocorrendo em um ou em dois momentos, na hora de serializar os dados para enviar ao serviço, ou na hora do serviço deserializar os dados enviados.

Comment: Se possível te sugiro colocar o serviço para rodar em modo depuração colocar um ponto de parada (breakpoint) no controller que recebe a requisiçãoe inspecionar o objeto recebido para assim poder visualizar se os dados estão chegando corretamente, caso contrário o problema está no lado cliente(app mobile)